# Cortex M33 unable to get stack pointer and pc from word offset 0/1 with qemu

Tags: arm, qemu, cortex-m

I tried to bringup cortex m33 with QEMU, and I used board MPS2-AN505, but QEMU always abort with HardFault error, so I checked system registers with GDB and I found that the T bit of ESPR reg is 0 after CPU boot, and the pc/sp is 0 too, but I have already write SP value and PC value into memory word offset 0/1
[image: system regs and mem word offset 0,1]
I also checked VTOR which defines the vector tables and it is 0, so sp /pc should be read out from  word offset 0/1

But if I used GDB to load elf files again, the T bit of ESPR is 1 but pc/sp still not be loaded. so the program start from address 0.
[image: after load from gdb, T bit is 1,pc/sp still 0]
I also tried with board type MPS3-AN547 which used corte-m55 with the same software code and vector table, and it works fine. PC / SP can be loaded correctly from word offset 0/1.

the QEMU version that I used is 6.2.0, and I used option -kernel xxx.bin to load my software image.

[qemu error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VYJ6.png)
as described above ...

[qemu error debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP6Qx.png)

Comment: The best way to debug this kind of early-bootup issue in QEMU is to turn on some of the -d logging flags to show where QEMU is trying to load the reset PC/SP, what it's loading, and any subsequent exceptions being taken, eg "-d cpu,int,guest_errors,unimp,in_asm". You can use "-D log.txt" if there's so much output you want to send it to a file. It may also be worth trying with a newer QEMU. (Older versions had a bug with resetting when the ELF file is loaded to an alias of the low RAM, as yours is doing -- I think that was fixed in 6.2, though.)

Comment: Hi @PeterMaydell , very appreciate for your comment, it is really helpful, I tried with -d option , seems QEMU was trying to load pc/sp from 0x1000 0000 which is the alias address of 0x0000 0000, is this the bug that you have mentioned above ?

Comment: I'm unable to insert picture here so  I put the capture of log info with -d option in the body of question , please check above

Comment: If you use a newer QEMU version the logging will be more informative, we improved it a bit since 6.2.

Comment: please post the actual vector table that you have generated.  the reset vector address needs bit 0 set.  but also when using qemu as perhaps Peter is describing for you may have to do more work in the construction of the elf binary as it uses things like the entry address that a real mcu woudnt because the mcu operates off of flash/memory and not a high level elf binary file.  but qemu can consume either.

Comment: please cut and paste the text not use pictures...